# Multiprojects with the same version on jenkins with Maven

Tags: maven, jenkins, version-control, jenkins-pipeline, continuous-delivery

I have 3 (actually I have 50+, but let's say 3 to simplify things) projects on 3 different repositories:

```
- parentpom (only a pom.xml)
- project1 (parent=parentpom)
- project2 (dependent on project1)
```

I want all of them to have always the same version.

I tried using `${revision}` but it doesn't work for me, in fact revision needs either the relativePath of the `pom.xml` where it has to look for the value of the properties, or it needs the project to be declared as a sub module of the parentpom.

In both cases I need to declare relative paths in order to make `${revision}` work, and that it's not possible with Jenkins, since those projects are located in different repositories, and their jenkins folder's name is not the same as the project's name, so it'd be a mess.

I also thought about defining the revision number in a property for every project, and then change it by command line from a job when the parentpom version is changed. The only problem is that when I run

```
mvn project1 -Drevision=2.2.0 install
```

it just doesn't work because Jenkins can't resolve the `${revision}` in the parent from the properties

If you have any suggestion on how to synchronize the versions of those projects automatically it'd be really appreciated

Comment: You can't.  This must be hardcoded in the pom.

Comment: If the projects should have the same version this is an indicator having them within a single repository and not separated.

Comment: The problem is that I have too many projects, and it'd be very complicated to mantain them having all them in one repository

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long research, I recognized that what I want is an antipattern, compared to how Maven works, so we're considering to group all the project in a few multimodule repository, so that we can have a unique versione by using ${revision}